# Rerender template will not update links

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a template to render a view for a user which has a tab bar to show followers,and others.

```
<h3>{{name}}</h3>
<img {{bindAttr src="avatar"}}  alt=""/>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active">{{#linkTo 'user.followers' this}}Followers{{/linkTo}}</li>
  <li class="active">{{#linkTo 'user.following' this}}Following{{/linkTo}}</li>
  <li class="active">{{#linkTo 'user.messages' this}}Messages{{/linkTo}}</li>
</ul>

{{outlet}}
```

Everything works fine when the template is rendered the first time. When I switch from one user to one of its followers the name and image is changing but the links in the tab bar are not updated.

Comment: Which version of Ember are you using?

Comment: its ember v1.0.0-rc.7

Comment: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/2181 says this problem should be solved. You are talking about updating the href, right?

Comment: Yes the href of the links is still the same when switch to another user.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
<h3>{{name}}</h3>
<img {{bindAttr src="avatar"}}  alt=""/>
{{#with this}}
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active">{{#linkTo 'user.followers' this}}Followers{{/linkTo}}</li>
  <li class="active">{{#linkTo 'user.following' this}}Following{{/linkTo}}</li>
  <li class="active">{{#linkTo 'user.messages' this}}Messages{{/linkTo}}</li>
</ul>
{{/with}}

{{outlet}}
```

The `{{#with}}` helper should make the inner code bound. I found this proposed solution in this [github issue](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/2181).

Comment: Unfortunately this don't.